# Encryption Password typing issues

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, password, encryption, special-characters

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.
Upon rebooting, after upgrade finished, I was asked to enter disk encryption password (not loggin password. I have full disk encyption).
My defalt keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04 was EN but upon upgrading it was set to SR (Serbian Latinic).
The huge issue now is that my encryption password last two characters are: ]]
However square brackets are not available at serbian keyboard.
I do not know how to type my password now. And as I know you cannot change keyboard before encryption.
Is there any solution or all my data is lost?

Comment: How was the keyboard layout changed? Was it changed in BIOS or within Ubuntu? Can you boot the commuter from a live Ubuntu installation USB using the Try Ubuntu option (with EN keyboard)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tip @user68186
The BIOS was on EN.

The way to go around this issue is:
*boot the commuter from a live Ubuntu installation USB using the Try Ubuntu option (with EN keyboard).
*change the encryption password using:https://mdik.codeberg.page/how-to-change-passwords-in-ubuntu-20.04.html 
*boot normally.
*enter a new password (with normal characters)

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅ after the wait period.